# Moving Articles From A Blog to Another Blog

Tags: seo

I was writing on a blog (source blog) which all users can publish their articles. But now this blog will be closed. SO i want to move my articles to my personal blog. But I'm worrying about Google Sandbox.

Can i move my articles to my personal blog without any SEO mistake ?

(NOTE : I'm not owner of source blog so i can't do a 301 Forwarding etc.)

Comment: Which blog platform are you migrating from? Depending on the software there may be tools which help with the redirection and SEO settings also.

Comment: I'm not owner of this blog so i cant do 301 forwarding.

Answer (score 3):

So long as you can include some `301 moved permanently` markers on the old content it should be fine.

**Edit**

If you don't have access to do this yourself (as you have mentioned in comments) then I would suggest just taking a potential SEO hit and putting them on your site.  If possible get the original blog to put up a link to the new content (you might have editor access).  If they are unwilling to do anything at all there is little you can do.

Comment: I'm not owner of this blog so i cant do 301 forwarding.

Comment: Would it be an option to ask them to do it?

Comment: there are too many users, i don't think they don't this

Answer (score 1):

If the other blog is going away and the content will no longer be available then republish it all at your blog when the other site goes offline. You'll avoid duplicate content issues because the other site will no longer exist. And if there is a sandbox, and you can't do 301 redirects, then there is no "perfect" solution. But if you republish the content and wait it out you will eventually be fully indexed and ranked. It may not happen as fast as you like but it will happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't the blog owner, you don't really have many options since when you file a transfer notice with Google or another major search engine, they'll require you to be the owner of the domain in order for you to file any notice.

Depending on what host you have now, you might be able to register a domain and point it to your articles and then have that domain redirected to your new website.

Aside from that exporting your articles and adding them to your new site (ideally identically along with the same timestamps from when the posts were added) would at least help in that Google will have content to index on the new site vs. just having it see a fresh install with one or two posts.